There is something like OPENJSON?
In this moment I'm using SQLSERVER to store json data into a Table. I do it using OPENJSON. Here is an example how I do it:
INSERT INTO myTable (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT jDataA, jDataB, jDataC
  FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$.data') 
  WITH (jDataA varchar(4),
        jDataB int,
        jDataC varchar(48));

The json data is:
{
    "data": [{
            "jDataA": "AAAA",
            "jDataB": 1,
            "jDataC": "OK"
        }, {
            "jDataA": "BBBB",
            "jDataB": 2,
            "jDataC": "OK"
        }, {
            "jDataA": "CCCC",
            "jDataB": 3,
            "jDataC": "BAD"
        }, {
            "jDataA": "DDDD",
            "jDataB": 4,
            "jDataC": "BAD"
        }
    ]
}

Now I want to migrate to MySQL (8.0), but I can't find something like OPENJSON. There are functions like JSON_EXTRACT, but I feel it is pretty limited.
Can you tell me how to implement an "insert from json" using mysql?

JSON_TABLE perhaps? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table

This can be done using JSON_TABLE function as follows :
SELECT jDataA, jDataB, jDataC
  FROM JSON_TABLE (
                   @JSON, 
                  '$.data[*]' 
                   COLUMNS( 
                      jDataA varchar(4) PATH '$.jDataA',
                      jDataB varchar(4) PATH '$.jDataB',
                      jDataC varchar(4) PATH '$.jDataC'
                   ) 
                  ) as s

